# Bokeh UI not working with DASK on another host

Tags: bokeh, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask.distributed

I've ran dask with bokeh on a cluster with 4 machines.
Now I've opened the dask ui page, on :8787,

We can see the graphs etc. are not there
[Empty UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU1Zw.png)

But the normal text and simple graphic are there
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beQOv.png)

I'm getting this error in the console.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zCdC.png)